# Textfield's label gets clipped when inside a Dialog

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When using a `Textfield` as the first child of DialogContent:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
        <Dialog open={true}>
          <DialogTitle>Hey</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
          <TextField
              fullWidth
              id='name'
              label={'Foo'}
              name='name'
              required
              type='text'
              value={'Bar'}
          />
          </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
  );
}
```

its label (when using `variant="outlined") gets clipped. See [codebox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-benji-25h72?file=/src/App.js). Any way to fix this problem? e.g. by customizing the theme?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily fix that issue by adding some margin to the TextField like the following.

```
sx={{ marginTop: 2 }}
```

Or you could wrap the TextField using [Box](https://mui.com/components/box/#main-content) inside the DialogContent like the following.

```
<Box p={1}>
  <TextField
    ...
  />
</Box>
```